# How to wrap item in a flex-box in N x N grid pattern

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can we wrap items inside a flex box in a N x N manner. Consider there are 4 items inside a  then on flex wrap there should wrap in a 2 x 2 grid manner. If the count increases 4 then in a 3 x n till the count of items inside the div is less than 9 and so on. 
Moreover the parent div should adjust it's width as per the number of items in the row. 
Please suggest some solution or any reference.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post your code here so we can help...?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ will give you a lot of good info on these two different layout approaches.